# select option hide jquery function not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I have two selectbox customer and period .In customer I have two option 'c6' and 'no client',In period  select box I have 'project life cycle' and 'temporary use' option.I want to hide period option 'project life cycle' when I choose 'no client' in customer selectbox.
 I have tried as

```js
$('#customer_name').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#customer_name').val() == '0') {
    $('#period option[value="2"]').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker default" id="customer_name" tabindex="9" name="account_name">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="USA_0012">C6</option>
  <option value="0">No Client</option>
</select>
<select class="selectpicker travel_purpose default period" id="period" tabindex="17" name="period">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="2">Project Life Cycle</option>
  <option value="1">Temporary Use</option>
</select>
```

This is working in firefox and chrome but not in IE browser

Comment: Did you try running this snippet in the question through IE browser?

Comment: ya tried in IE browser not working as chrome

Answer (score 0):

use the generic code which works on all platforms

```
$('#customer_name').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#customer_name').val() == '0') {
    $('#period option[value="2"]').css('display','none');
  }
});
```